# Why is the font-weight attribute does not work in the span tag?

Tags: html, css, bold

I tried using a font-weight attribute in my span tag in a html document, but it seems that it does not have any effect.

But, when I used the `font-weight` in the CSS document, it works just perfectly.

For example, I have a `div` where I assigned a class to it, inside a d`i`v there is a `header` that I want to bold a few words in it using the span tag, but it does not work.

But, in the CSS document, I tried to use the font-weight attribute using the class selector, and it works.

I'm out of ideas...

Here is my html and CSS document:

```css
.beamember {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.membercontent {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 90px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="beamember">
    <div class="membercontent">
        <h5><span style="font-weight:bolder;">Sign up</span>to get more benefits !</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent elit odio,
            venenatis et nunc at,
            fringilla accumsan felis. Sed vestibulum gravida pulvinar. Nullam posuere et orci sed semper. Phasellus ligula leo,
            dignissim sed leo sit amet,
            convallis pretium urna. Etiam diam turpis,
            maximus nec lobortis nec,
            congue nec sem. Phasellus pellentesque purus eros,
            id imperdiet felis venenatis quis. In sit amet odio dolor.</p><a href="#">Register Now !</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

First make sure your font support fontweight of 900.

`h5` default `font-weight` is `bold` which is equivalent of `700`.
If you want to use `font-weight:bolder` on its nested tag it is going to be `900`.
Value bolder is relative unit which means it will set `font-weight` according to your parent tag. Font weight of bolder for 100, 200, 300 is 400, for 400, 500  is 700, for 600, 700, 800, 900 is 900

Comment: detailed mention about `font-weight`. Upvoting this.

Comment: thank you for this, I tried to see if there is any slight difference between the bold and normal ones but I dont. Maybe because like you said it's the font that is causing this. Thank you!